# Best way to return token after github authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I have an angular app that is using passport-github2 and oauth2 to both authenticate and gain access to github resources.  I am using nodejs, koa and passport github and my server code looks a bit like this in the callback that is called by github:

```
router.get('/auth/github/callback', function* (next) {
  const ctx = this;

  yield passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }, function* (err, profile, failed) {
    if(!err && profile) {
      const token = jwtHelper(profile);
      ctx.redirect(config.client.syncUrl + '?token=' + token);
```

In the frontend with angular, I am going to do something like this to get the token:

```
const token = location.query.token
```

I would rather send the token in a response header but I don't know how to pull the header out in the frontend angular code.

Is it possible to work with a response header in this way?

Comment: How are you serving the application? Are you using Express?

Comment: I am using koa, I mentioned that in the question,, sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

From [koa's documentation](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/response.md#responsesetfield-value):

**response.set(field, value)**

Set response header field to value:

```
this.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
```

So in your case it should be something like:

```
ctx.set('Token', token)
```

Comment: This explains how to send the token from the server but not how to work with it on the front-end, which is what OP was asking for.